# Retrive base64-file from multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: java, base64, http-post

I receive a request (multipart/form-data POST), parameter "file" contains file as a base64 (example below)

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryEA37wQGzpnprPt8x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"file\"\r\n\r\nJVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwvQXV0aG9yIChNYXJrbyBLZWpcMjM2YXIpL0Ny\r\nZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDE2MTEyMjExMzc0NCswMScwMCcpL0NyZWF0b3IgKE1TIFdvcmQg\r\nRG9jdW1lbnQ

I am curious how to decode it (using JAVA of course) from there and get a file.

1. Should I somehow delete system information (**WebKitFormBoundary** and **Content-Disposition**)?
2. I also noticed that content full of **\r\n** Do I need to delete it myself as well?

Comment: What server technology are you using? Servlet? --- Also, that looks like the content of a `multipart/form-data` POST. If you look at the HTTP header `Content-Type`, you'll see that type. You should search the web for more information about how `multipart/form-data` works.

Comment: @Andreas it is Servlet and es, it is multipart/form-data. OK, I will read of course more, but a code-tip would be great ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use following link to decode from base64

- https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: thanks, but my question is more about how to do it programatically)